# Rust way of magic methods

Tags: oop, rust

I want to map all children struct methods to it's parent with reducing some parameters.

Here is a example:-

PlayGround:- https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0610b6abd57ab3d65435c821829e156b

```rust
struct World;
struct Sibling;

struct Parent {
    pub child: Child,
    pub sibling: Sibling
}

impl Parent {
    pub fn new()->Parent {
        Parent {
            sibling: Sibling,
            child: Child,
        }
    }
}

struct Child;

impl Child {
    pub fn set_x(&mut self, _world: &mut World, _sibling: &mut Sibling, _x: f32 ){
        // ..
    }

    pub fn set_y(&mut self, _world: &mut World, _sibling: &mut Sibling, _y: f32){
        // ..
    }

    // 32 methods that taking World as first parameter and Sibling as second parameter
}

fn main(){

    let mut world = World;

    let mut parent = Parent::new();

    parent.child.set_x(&mut world,&mut parent.sibling,0.23);
    parent.child.set_y(&mut world,&mut parent.sibling, 0.12);

    // Expectation:-
    // parent.set_x(&mut world,0.23)
    // parent.set_y(&mut world, 1.23)

}
```

Parent is know who is the sibling, who is the child. There is no need for guidance from the global scope. I need to hide child and sibling from outer scope. And I have tried in the following way.

```rust
impl Parent {

    pub fn set_x(&mut self, world: &mut World, x: f32){
        self.child.set_x(world, &mut self.sibling, x);
    }

    // ...
}
```

But I have 32 methods. This is not a clear way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple macro:

```
macro_rules! map_methods {
    ($stype:ty { $($method:ident ($($param:ident : $ptype:ty),*);)* }) => {
        impl $stype {
            $(
            fn $method (&mut self, world: &mut World, $($param: $ptype),*) {
                self.child.$method (world, &mut self.sibling, $($param),*)
            }
            )*
        }
    }
}
```

Which you then use like this:

```
map_methods!{ Parent {
    set_x (_x: f32);
    set_y (_y: f32);
}}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b54c9b7d8a8deacdbf08a8ec07459d10)

PS: Obligatory reading when starting with Rust macros: [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/)